# How to specify Vorbis encoding options using `sox`?

Tags: sox, vorbis

I want to record audio encoded using Vorbis quality level 6, but how to pass the encode options to `rec`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`soxformat(7)`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html) man page:

> SoX  can decode all types of Ogg Vorbis files, and can encode at
>                 different compression levels/qualities given as a number from -1
>                 (highest  compression/lowest quality) to 10 (lowest compression,
>                 highest quality).  By default the encoding quality  level  is  3
>                 (which  gives  an encoded rate of approx. 112kbps), but this can
>                 be changed using the `-C` option (see above) with a number from -1
>                 to  10; fractional numbers (e.g.  3.6) are also allowed.